# Open source multiphysics software that can model the interaction of two insulators with a user-specified electrical force law?

Tags: electromagnetism, open-source, multiphysics

Given two solid bodies of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ with invariable charge distributions $\rho_1(\mathbf{r_1})$ and $\rho_2(\mathbf{r_2})$ in them,* respectively, I would like to model the electrical interaction of the bodies using a user-specified electrical force law.

<sup>* $\mathbf{r_1}$ and $\mathbf{r_2}$ are measured with respect to a coordinate system fixed to body 1 and body 2, respectively.</sup>

What open source multiphysics software packages could I use to model the motion of these bodies?

Comment: I don't know of any software that can do this. But I imagine that you can combine a Boundary element method and a time integration scheme (like Verlet integration) for each iteration ... but I doubt that it is optimal.